# Is there any ways to set values to system fields of CloudWatch Logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I want to set values to the fields `@requestId` in lambda executions because logs outputted explicitly inside the source code does not contain the `@requestId` field value. 
I've read [an article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-fields.html) and tried to output logs like the below but the @requestId did not to be filled.

```
fmt.Print(`{"requestId":"come on!!"}`)
```

Neither the below code.

```
fmt.Print(`{"@requestId":"come on!!"}`)
```

Are system fields protected?

Answer (score 0):

When an AWS Lambda function is triggered, a `context` element is passed to the function.

From [AWS Lambda Function Handler in Go - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-handler-types.html):

```golang
func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, name MyEvent) (string, error) {
        return fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s!", name.Name ), nil
}
```

From [AWS Lambda Context Object in Go - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-context.html):

> **Context Properties**
>
> `AwsRequestID` – The identifier of the invocation request.

Therefore, you can retrieve the Request ID from the `context`. Then, anything that your function prints will be captured in **CloudWatch Logs**. So, include the Request ID in your print statement.